# What is the meaning of int[]

Tags: c, function, coding-style, int

What is the meaning of `int[]` in C programming when you declare it? Like in this code

```
int findPivot(int[], int, int);
```

Comment: In the given code, it is an `int*`, a pointer to `int`.

Comment: It is an array of `int`. [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `int[]` - array of int, e.g. a pointer to the array of ints.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you are asking about *function parameters* of type `int[]`, in this particular case it is equivalent to pointer to `int`, i.e. `int*`. There is no difference between the two. In other contexts, `int[]` may have a different meaning.

These two function declarations are the same:

```
void foo(int[]);
void foo(int*);
```

And both are equivalent to this:

```
void foo(int[42]);
```

If you were to define more than one of them, you'd get a multiple definition error

```
void foo(int[]) {}
void foo(int*) {} // ERROR! Multiple definition.
```

Now, since C allows arrays to decay to pointers, you can actually invoke `foo` with an array of `int` as *argument*. The array decays to a pointer to its first element.

```
int a[42];
int b[99];
int c;
foo(a);
foo(b);
foo(&c);
```

Since the decay is to a pointer, all array size information is lost.

Answer (score 2):

In this function declaration

```
int findPivot(int[], int, int);
```

int[] - is a declaration of the function parameter as having type of an array of integers with unknown number elements. So it is an incomplete type.

The compiler adjusts this declaration to pointer. So these two function declarations are equivalent

```
int findPivot(int[], int, int);
int findPivot(int *, int, int);
```

When you pass an array as the corresponding argument of the parameter it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. So the number of elements in the array is unimportant. Thus the above two declarations can be appended with a declaration of the function where the number of elements in the array is specified. For example

```
int findPivot(int[10], int, int);
int findPivot(int[20], int, int);
int findPivot(int[], int, int);
int findPivot(int *, int, int);
```

These declarations declare the same one function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int findPivot(int[], int, int);
```

is a function declaration. At times, it is called a [Forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) or [Function prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) also.

FWIW, in a function declaration, you're allowed to omit the variable names, only specifying the variable type is enough.

In **this particular context**, an `int[]` and `int*` carries the same meaning, i.e., `int[]` here refers that the function accepts a pointer to an `int` as the first parameter .

While calling the function, we can either pass

- a pointer to an `int` or
- an `int` array (because of [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/2173917) effect while passing the argument, array type argument boils down to a pointer).

You can call the function as

```
#define MAX 128

int actualArray[MAX] = {0};
int p = <somevalue>;
int q = <someothervalue>;
//somecode 
int retval = findPivot(actualArray, p, q);
```

Comment: Saying it accepts an `int` array as first parameter is correct but misleading. It accepts any pointer to `int`.

Comment: Maybe just saying that the first parameter really is an `int*`, but it can accept an array argument because of array decay?

Comment: OK, array *decay* is what lets you pass an array name as *argument* to a function with a pointer *parameter*. So `int[]` isn't `int*` because of decay. It is so because the type gets *adjusted* to pointer. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's better! And there's no need for that "sir" business ;-)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. And regarding the "sir", it's [MMM](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWYLFizhjHs).

Answer (score 0):

In the case you specified, it specifies that first position of that function with parameter stub `int[]` is available to any array parameter

if its in an assignement like this

`int values[] = {9, 2, 6, 1, 4};`

it means values will be created with as many array items as added when that array is initialized, in this case 5.

Answer (score -1):

findPivot expects an [int array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) and two `int` variables. The `int` array is effectively a set of integer values. It is equivalent to an [int pointer](http://boredzo.org/pointers/) in this case.

Comment: Can you tell me why do you consider this answer to be unhelpful?